# Duplicar campo - MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException - Java

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente **SQL**:

```
CREATE TABLE clientes (
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    dni VARCHAR(9) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    telefono VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    direccion VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    ciudad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Mi problema está en el campo "**`email`**".

Bien, tengo un archivo **.java** en el cual puedo actualizar los datos de un cliente. Por ejemplo, al `clienteA`, que tiene un mail `clientea@gmail.com`, quiero cambiarle el **teléfono** del `111222333` al `333222111`. **¿Por qué no me permite hacerlo y me dice que "Este email YA existe en la agenda", cuando estoy actualizando al MISMO cliente, y no agregando otro cliente con ese mail?** Teniendo en cuenta que el `111222333` no puede ser utilizado posteriormente por ningún cliente.

**1** ¿Debo guardar todos los mails y todos los teléfonos para que NO se repitan en OTROS clientes?

**2** ¿Cuál sería la forma más sencilla y factible de solucionarlo?

Os muestro el **código del ACTUALIZAR:**

```
private void button_OKActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        //Atributos generales para el cliente.
        String nombre = textfield_nombre.getText();
        String apellidos = textfield_apellidos.getText();
        String DNI = (String) jComboBox_DNIs.getSelectedItem();
        String telefono = textfield_telefono.getText();
        String direccion = textfield_direccion.getText();
        String ciudad = textfield_ciudad.getText();
        String email = textfield_email.getText();

        //Comprobamos que están todos los datos insertados...
        if (!textfield_email.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !textfield_telefono.getText().trim().isEmpty() && !textfield_direccion.getText().trim().isEmpty() 
            && !textfield_ciudad.getText().trim().isEmpty()) {
            if(!isTelefono(textfield_telefono.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡El teléfono debe contener 9 dígitos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                textfield_telefono.requestFocus();
            }else if(!isEmail(textfield_email.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Formato de email incorrecto!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                textfield_email.requestFocus();
            }else if(Conexiones.cargar_email().contains(textfield_email.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Este email YA existe en la agenda!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                textfield_email.requestFocus();
            }else{
                Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nombre, apellidos, DNI, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email);
                //Llamamos al método modificar_cliente() para modificar el cliente en la base de datos.
                Conexiones.modificar_cliente(cliente);
                dispose();
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Debes rellenar TODOS los campos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_telefono.requestFocus();
            textfield_telefono.setBackground(Color.decode("0xB4FF48"));
        }
    }
```

**modificar_cliente():**

```
public static void modificar_cliente(Cliente cliente){
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try{
            //Preparamos la consulta a realizar...
            stm = c.createStatement();
            //Consulta para modificar un cliente en la base de datos.
            String modificar_clientes = " UPDATE clientes "
                    + " SET nombre = '"+cliente.getNombre()+"', apellidos = '"+cliente.getApellidos()+"', "
                    + " DNI = '"+cliente.getDNI()+"', telefono = '"+cliente.getTelefono()+"', "
                    + " direccion = '"+cliente.getDireccion()+"', ciudad = '"+cliente.getCiudad()+"', "
                    + " email = '"+cliente.getEmail()+"' WHERE DNI = '"+cliente.getDNI()+"';";

            int resultado1 = 1;
            //System.out.println(modificar_clientes);
            resultado1 = stm.executeUpdate(modificar_clientes);
            if(resultado1<=0){
                throw new SQLException();
            }else{
                //System.out.println("Cliente modificado en la tabla clientes.");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modificación realizada con éxito.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Conexiones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Y la función **cargar_mails()**:

```
public static ArrayList cargar_email() {
        ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los emails de la tabla "clientes".
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_emails = "SELECT email FROM clientes ORDER BY email ASC";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_emails);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS emails: Mostramos todos los emails de la tabla 'clientes'.");
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                emails.add(email);
                i++;
            }
            //System.out.println(emails);
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ha habido un error.");
        }     
        return emails;
    }
```

Comment: Debes delegar la tarea, de comprobar si existe, a la base de datos. O sea no uses `cargar_email()` y provoca el error que lanza la base de datos. Luego decime el nombre de la excepción que muestra la consola

Comment: @JuanRom ¿a la base de datos? ¿Mi forma no es correcta? Osea debo modificar esta línea de código: else if(Conexiones.cargar_email().contains(textfield_email.getText())){

Comment: claro por que esa linea comprueba si el email del textField ya existe en la base. Entonces comentala así se produce el error, luego me pasas el nombre de la excepción lanzada, que creo que es `ConstraintViolationException` pero chequealo

Comment: Si comento la línea esa, entonces salta directamente al else, y me realiza la modificación. No me salta ninguna excepción. Automáticamente me dice "Modificación realizada con éxito".

Comment: o sea que te dejo duplicar el campo `email`?

Comment: run:
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'anarosa@hotmail.com' for key 'email'

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107706/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-juan-rom).

Comment: ¿Alguna posible solución?

Comment: Osmar ya lo tengo probado y funciona, lanza y captura la excepcion de la db, en breve publico la respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hagamos unas pequeñas modificaciones:

1. Olvídate de comprobar si existe email, o sea **desecha** el método **Conexiones.cargar_email()**
2. Usa **BUSCAR_CLIENTE(String dni)** para **rescatar** el **cliente** escogido del **combo box**, luego si el **cliente** **no** sale **null** se pasa a llamar a **MODIFICAR_CLIENTE(Cliente clien)**
3. En **MODIFICAR_CLIENTE(Cliente clien)** se permite al usuario **actualizar** todos los campos **excepto** **dni**, este dni solo se lo usa para buscar cliente en las consultas SQL

Un ejemplo sin interfaz visual, llamando desde clase main (Principal), que sería tu ActionEvent (button_OKActionPerformed):

```
//clase Conexion

import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public static Cliente BUSCAR_CLIENTE(String dni){

        Connection c = (Connection) CONECTAR_DB();
        PreparedStatement pstm =null;
        ResultSet rs =null;
        Cliente clie =null;
        try {

            pstm =c.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM cliente where dni = ?");
            pstm.setString(1, dni);
            rs =pstm.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) //verifico si hay y desplazo el puntero al siguiente elemento
            {
                rs.beforeFirst();//esta regresa el puntero al inicio
                clie =new Cliente();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    clie.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                    clie.setApellido(rs.getString("apellido"));
                    clie.setDni(rs.getString("dni"));
                    clie.setTelefono(rs.getString("telefono"));
                    clie.setDireccion(rs.getString("direccion"));
                    clie.setCiudad(rs.getString("ciudad"));
                    clie.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                }  
            }
            else
            {
                //dni inexistente o inválido
                throw new Exception();
            } 
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de Base de Datos."
            + "\n"+e.getMessage()+"\nCódigo error: "+e.getErrorCode()
              ,"Excepción SQL",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "dni inválido."
            + "\nEl dni no existe en la base de datos"
              ,"Excepción ",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                if(c !=null)
                    c.close();
                if(rs !=null)
                    rs.close();
                if(pstm !=null)
                    pstm.close();

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return clie;
    }  


public static void MODIFICAR_CLIENTE(Cliente cliente){

        //estos serian los textos de los JTextField
        String txtNombre ="Pepe";
        String txtApellido ="Lopez";
        //dni no se pide
        String txtTelefono ="4587963";
        String txtDireccion ="Belgrano 123";
        String txtCiudad ="Buenos Aires";
        String txtEmail ="pepe123@gmail.com";
//        String txtEmail ="ana@gmail.com";//para provocar MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException

        //seteamos el cliente recibido
        cliente.setNombre(txtNombre);
        cliente.setApellido(txtApellido);
        //dni no se toca
        cliente.setTelefono(txtTelefono);
        cliente.setDireccion(txtDireccion);
        cliente.setCiudad(txtCiudad);
        cliente.setEmail(txtEmail);

        Connection c = (Connection) CONECTAR_DB();
        Statement stm =null;

        try{
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String query = " UPDATE cliente "
                    + " SET nombre = '"+cliente.getNombre()+"', apellido = '"+cliente.getApellido()
                    + "', telefono = '"+cliente.getTelefono()+"', direccion = '"+cliente.getDireccion()
                    + "', ciudad = '"+cliente.getCiudad()+"',  email = '"+cliente.getEmail()
                    + "' WHERE dni = '"+cliente.getDni()+"';";
            //dni no se actualiza, solo se usa para cláusula where

            stm.executeUpdate(query);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Modificación realizada con éxito.");
        }
        catch (MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException ex) {

             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entrada Duplicada"
                + "\n"+ex.getMessage()+"\nCódigo error: "+ex.getErrorCode()
                  ,"Excepción Reestricción de Base de Datos",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error."
            + "\n" + e.getMessage() + "\nCódigo error: " + e.getErrorCode()
              ,"Excepción SQL",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        finally {
            try {
                c.close();
                if(stm !=null)
                    stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

public static ArrayList<Cliente> LISTA_CLIENTES() {
        ArrayList<Cliente> clientes = new ArrayList<>();
        Connection c = (Connection) CONECTAR_DB();
        Statement stm =null;
        ResultSet rs =null;
        try {

            stm = c.createStatement();
            String query = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next())
            {
                clientes.add(new Cliente(
                          rs.getString("nombre")
                        , rs.getString("apellido"), rs.getString("dni")
                        , rs.getString("telefono"), rs.getString("direccion")
                        , rs.getString("ciudad"), rs.getString("email")));

            }                   
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error."
            + "\n" + e.getMessage() + "\nCódigo error: " + e.getErrorCode()
              ,"Excepción SQL",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                if(c !=null)
                    c.close();
                if(rs !=null)
                    rs.close();
                if(stm !=null)
                    stm.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Conexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        return clientes;
    }

        //Así llamo desde mi clase Principal:
        ArrayList<Cliente> clientes =Conexion.LISTA_CLIENTES();
        System.out.println("lista clientes antes del update");

        for(Cliente c:clientes)
            System.out.println(c);

        System.out.println("modificando cliente 1");

        //dni de cliente que traes del combo
        String dniSelec ="30123456";//dni de pepe
        //String dniSelec ="111122223333";//dni inválido para provocar SQLException
        Cliente cliente =null;
        cliente =Conexion.BUSCAR_CLIENTE(dniSelec);

        //método Conexion.MODIFICAR_CLIENTE(cliente) no puede recibir cliente null
        if(cliente !=null)
            Conexion.MODIFICAR_CLIENTE(cliente);

        System.out.println("lista clientes despues del update");
        clientes =Conexion.LISTA_CLIENTES();
        for(Cliente c:clientes)
            System.out.println(c);
```

[image]

[image]

Ahora provoco una **MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException** al ponerle a **Pepe** el **email** de **Ana**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Hola @omaza1990 antes que nada me parece bien tu código solo existen algunos temitas que debes de cambiar.

Empezaré por el método cargar_mails.
Este método esta muy bien si es que se cargan todos los emails antes de cualquier cosa y que sea transversal para el proyecto, aunque no lo recomiendo, mi recomendación es que cambies este método recibiendo el email a validar.

```
   public static ArrayList cargar_email(String dni) {
        ArrayList<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los emails de la tabla "clientes".
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_emails = "SELECT email FROM clientes where DNI !='" +dni+"'";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_emails);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS emails: Mostramos todos los emails de la tabla 'clientes'.");
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String email = rs.getString("email");
                emails.add(email);
                i++;
            }
            //System.out.println(emails);
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ha habido un error.");
        }     
        return emails;
    }
```

Lo segundo seria modificar el método button_OKActionPerformed en el siguiente código

```
  }else if(Conexiones.cargar_email(DNI).contains(textfield_email.getText())){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Este email YA existe en la agenda!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_email.requestFocus();
        }else{
            Cliente cliente = new Cliente(nombre, apellidos, DNI, telefono, direccion, ciudad, email);
            //Llamamos al método modificar_cliente() para modificar el cliente en la base de datos.
            Conexiones.modificar_cliente(cliente);
            dispose();
        }
```

Por último el método modificar_cliente

```
//Preparamos la consulta a realizar...
        stm = c.createStatement();
        //Consulta para modificar un cliente en la base de datos.
        String modificar_clientes = " UPDATE clientes "
                + " SET nombre = '"+cliente.getNombre()+"', apellidos = '"+cliente.getApellidos()+"', "
                +"', telefono = '"+cliente.getTelefono()+"', "
                + " direccion = '"+cliente.getDireccion()+"', ciudad = '"+cliente.getCiudad()+"', "+ " email = '"+cliente.getEmail()+"'"
                +"' WHERE DNI = '"+cliente.getDNI()+"';";

        int resultado1 = 1;
        //System.out.println(modificar_clientes);
        resultado1 = stm.executeUpdate(modificar_clientes);
```

Eliminamos el DNI  en el update ya que el DNI es la llave primaria.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. ¿Por qué actualizar el email? Y si como usuario cambias de email después de 5 años... por eso quería tratar ese asunto.

Comment: Estimado @omaza1990 si tu negocio requiere el cambio de email, entonces omite el segundo punto, ya te lo edito.

Comment: Ya esta mi estimado, ya modifiqué, lo que hice es que se filtre por el DNI y así en el select en donde te traes todos los emails, te traiga todos excepto el del cliente a modificar, así validará si existe el email con otros clientes. saludos